# Releasing software as Kopimi

Tags: public-domain

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piratbyr%C3%A5n#Kopimi

Essentially, I'm looking to release a piece of software as "Kopimi". I want to release it into the public domain so there is nothing stopping someone from using my work. However, can I still be held liable, since it doesn't explicitly release the author from liability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you linked to notes:

> While Kopimi may appear to be a radical free content license, in effect similar to Creative Commons Zero, no one associated with Piratbyrån ever called Kopimi a license, instead describing it as a symbol of certain ideas. The website of Kopimi contains no terms or legal text. The Open Source Initiative, Free Software Foundation, or any other organisation within the open-source movement, does not list Kopimi as an approved license.

The Kopimi symbol is just a symbol. People sometimes use it to mean, "Please use this however you like and I promise not to sue you," but it's not clear to me if a court would enforce such a vaguely implicit promise against you, the author, if you changed your mind and *did* decide to sue someone. This isn't a condemnation of the Kopimi symbol by any means, but merely my opinion that the Kopimi symbol is not a license (nor an acceptable substitute for one).

If you really want to license your work freely, then *actually attach a license to it* to promise a clearly-defined set of permissions to all your recipients. If you want to impose no restrictions on downstream distirbution and modification, I highly recommend CC0 (combination license and public-domain dedication) which is recommended [by the FSF](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#CC0) and [by Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F) for use on software. The CC0 license/dedication includes a disclaimer of liability.

Note that CC0 does not license any patent rights you may have in the software. CC0 is only a copyright license. If you want to license your patent rights, to assure recipients that you will never hold them liable for infringement of one of your patents, the [Apache 2.0 license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) is a permissive license that grants patent rights. However, it still requires attribution, which may be more restrictive than you want your absolutely-free license to be.